# XML Element not shown correnctly

Tags: android, android-layout

In my app I want to parse an XML file and add the elements to a view, this works quite good. But there is a little problem with more "complicated" XML Files, there are not shown correctly. For example when I take this file for input, the TextViews, except the last one, doesn't not appear on the screen?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/general_bg"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_newgame_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="25dip"
            android:paddingTop="10dip"
            android:text="New Game"
            android:textColor="@color/menu_title"
            android:textSize="24.5sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_newgame_profile"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:paddingBottom="20dip"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip"
            android:text="Profile: Denis"
            android:textColor="@color/menu_submenu"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.5dip"
            android:background="#999" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_newgame_difficulty"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:paddingBottom="5dip"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip"
            android:paddingTop="5dip"
            android:textColor="@color/menu_submenu"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekb_newgame_difficulty"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
            android:max="10"
            android:paddingLeft="20dip"
            android:paddingRight="20dip"
            android:progress="4" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.5dip"
            android:background="#999" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_newgame_showshadow"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                android:text="Show shadow"
                android:textColor="@color/menu_submenu"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkbox_newgame_shadow"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:paddingRight="20dip" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.5dip"
            android:background="#999" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_newgame_cooperative"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                android:text="Cooperative"
                android:textColor="@color/menu_submenu"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkbox_newgame_cooperative"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:paddingRight="20dip" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.5dip"
            android:background="#999" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="60dip" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_newgame_start"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="50dip"
                android:paddingRight="50dip"
                android:text="Start" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_newgame_back"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_conte
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="50dip"
                android:paddingRight="50dip"
                android:text="Back" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_start_status"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Status: Connected"
        android:textColor="@color/green_ok"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

So my question what I have to consider when I work with parsing, and why are the TextViews not displayed? Are they behind by other element or is there a clue with the RelativLayout?

Would be thankful for tips! :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `android:layout_height` for textviews greater than `0.5dip`(for example `10dip` or `15dip`),so they can be visible.
I change your layout and all textviews are visible:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/general_bg"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_newgame_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="25dip"
            android:paddingTop="10dip"
            android:text="New Game"
            android:textColor="@color/menu_title"
            android:textSize="24.5sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_newgame_profile"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:paddingBottom="20dip"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip"
            android:text="Profile: Denis"
            android:textColor="@color/menu_submenu"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="15dip"
            android:background="#999" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_newgame_difficulty"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:paddingBottom="5dip"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip"
            android:paddingTop="5dip"
            android:textColor="@color/menu_submenu"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekb_newgame_difficulty"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
            android:max="10"
            android:paddingLeft="20dip"
            android:paddingRight="20dip"
            android:progress="4" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="15dip"
            android:background="#999" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_newgame_showshadow"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                android:text="Show shadow"
                android:textColor="@color/menu_submenu"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkbox_newgame_shadow"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:paddingRight="20dip" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="15dip"
            android:background="#999" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_newgame_cooperative"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                android:text="Cooperative"
                android:textColor="@color/menu_submenu"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkbox_newgame_cooperative"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:paddingRight="20dip" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="15dip"
            android:background="#999" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="60dip" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_newgame_start"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="50dip"
                android:paddingRight="50dip"
                android:text="Start" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_newgame_back"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="50dip"
                android:paddingRight="50dip"
                android:text="Back" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_start_status"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Status: Connected"
        android:textColor="@color/green_ok"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: does not work.. i think there is something with the RelativLayout. the view is added to the layout but they are not displayed? and the strange thing is that the last Textview is shown but the others not...

Comment: @user1612540 I change your layout and all textviews are visible.Please try it.

Comment: I think you did not understand what the problem is stackoverflow.com/questions/12177667/textview-added-dynamically-is-not-visible-but-hides-other-elements#comment16311170_12177667